# Prove that there is a y that $f(y) = [f(x_1)+f(x_2)+ \cdots+ f(x_n) ]/ n$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

let $f : [a,b] \to \Bbb R$ a continuous function and $x_1,x_2,x_3,\cdots,x_n\in[a,b]$

**I need to prove/show that there is a $y \in [a,b]$ that:**

$$f(y) = \frac{f(x_1)+f(x_2)+ .... + f(x_n)}{n}$$

Any ideas about how to do it?

Comment: Hint: Arithmetic mean of $n$ numbers lies between their min and max. And then use Intermediate value theorem for continuous functions.

Comment: just saw it. thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Intermediate value theorem.

Consider the indices $j=\max(f (x_i))$ and $k=\min ( f(x_i) )$. Why must there be a $y$ in the interval $[x_j, x_k]$?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/554056/prove-
there-is-a-point-z-ina-b-at-which-fz-fracfx-1fx-2-cdotsfx

found it.thats what i mean.thanks a lot